# Arraylist duplicate entries if the item name is same

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

I have encountered a problem here in my code

**The scenario is**

when add an item from the spinner,It gets added to the side list 
and for the first time before pressing order button ,its text is set blue and  you can modify the quantity as well
[image]

-You add a second Item
[image]

-After pressing the order button,the order info is sent to db, the text is set to yellow  the order is placed and you should not be able to modify the items
[image]

-Now you add a **different** item to the next order [image]

-And you place the second order
[image]

-And if you add the same item 'Captain Morgan' then it gets added to the 2nd order [image]

Here is the all the code which handles the above operations

I'm using two fragments MainFragment and SideFragment

**SidePanelFragment.java**

```
    public class SidePanelFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

        ListView list1;



        ArrayList<Items> itemsArray = new ArrayList<Items>();
        ItemsAdapter1 adapter = null;
        boolean isPresent = false;
        Button btnCancel;
        Button btnOrder;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_side_panel, container, false);
            list1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewSide);
            btnCancel=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for(int i=0;i<itemsArray.size();i++){
                       if(!itemsArray.get(i).Ordered)
                           itemsArray.remove(i);
                    }
                    //itemsArray.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            btnOrder=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnOrder);
            btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    for(int i=0;i<itemsArray.size();i++){

                        if(!itemsArray.get(i).Ordered) {
                           // itemsArray.get(i).
                            itemsArray.get(i).Ordered = true;
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            adapter = new ItemsAdapter1(getActivity(), itemsArray);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list1.invalidateViews();
            list1.setAdapter(adapter);
            return view;
        }



        public void getAddedItems(Items item) {


            for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.size(); i++) {
                if (item.ItemName == itemsArray.get(i).ItemName) {
                    int quant = itemsArray.get(i).prevQuant;
                    item.quantity = item.quantity + quant;


                    itemsArray.set(i, item);

                    itemsArray.get(i).prevQuant = item.quantity;

                    isPresent = true;

                }
            }

            if (!isPresent) {

                itemsArray.add(item);
                itemsArray.get(itemsArray.size() - 1).prevQuant = item.quantity;


            }



            isPresent = false;
            adapter = new ItemsAdapter1(getActivity(), itemsArray);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list1.invalidateViews();
            list1.setAdapter(adapter);


        }



        class ItemsAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter {


            Context context;
            ArrayList<Items> itemList;

            ItemsAdapter1(Context context, ArrayList<Items> itemList1) {
                itemList = new ArrayList<Items>();
                this.context = context;
                itemList = itemList1;


            }


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return itemList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return itemList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }


            class ViewHolder {

                TextView txtView1;
                TextView txtView2;
                TextView txtView3;
                ImageButton imgBtn;
                Button btnQuantPlus;
                Button btnQuantMinus;

                ViewHolder(final View V) {

                    txtView1 = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.txtSideItemName);
                    txtView2 = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.txtSideQuant);
                    txtView3 = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.txtAmountSide);
                    //if (itemList.get().Ordered==false)
                    imgBtn = (ImageButton) V.findViewById(R.id.btndelete);
                    btnQuantPlus=(Button)V.findViewById(R.id.btnQuantPlus);
                    btnQuantMinus=(Button)V.findViewById(R.id.btnQuantMinus);


                }


            }


            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View row = convertView;
                ViewHolder holder = null;
                if (row == null) {


                    row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.side_panel_list, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder(row);


                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
                }
                Items it = itemList.get(position);
                holder.txtView1.setText(it.ItemName);
                holder.txtView2.setText(String.valueOf(it.Price));
                holder.txtView3.setText(String.valueOf(it.quantity));

                if(itemList.get(position).Ordered==false) {
                    holder.btnQuantMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if ((itemList.get(position).quantity) > 1) {
                                Items it = new Items();
                                it = itemList.get(position);

                                it.quantity = it.prevQuant - 1;
                                it.prevQuant = it.quantity;
                                itemList.set(position, it);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }


                        }

                    });


                    holder.btnQuantPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // if(it.quantity>1)
                            Items it = new Items();
                            it = itemList.get(position);

                            it.quantity = it.prevQuant + 1;
                            it.prevQuant = it.quantity;
                            itemList.set(position, it);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        }
                    });


                    holder.imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            itemList.remove(position);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    holder.imgBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.btnQuantMinus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.btnQuantPlus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


                //holder.imgBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                row.setTag(holder);


                holder.txtView3.setText(String.valueOf(itemList.get(position).quantity));
                setRowColor(row,position);
                return row;
            }

            private void setRowColor(View view, int var) {
                if(itemList.get(var).Ordered==true){
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e7ff00"));
                }else
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4585f2"));

                    //view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,0,255));

            }

        }
    }
```

**MainPanelFragment.java**

```
public class MainPanelFragment extends android.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    Spinner spinner;
    //ArrayList<String> listCatagories= null;
    ItemsAdapter adapter;
    ArrayAdapter adapter1;
    CategoriesAdapter catAdapter;
    ListView list;
    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemPrice;
    EditText quantity;
    Button quantPlus;
    Button quantMinus;
    Button addItem;
    int quantCount=1;

    ArrayList<Categories> catForAdapter=null;
    public String selectedItemName="";
    public double selectedItemPrice=0;
    public Items  selectedItem=null;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_menu,container,false);

        spinner=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCatagory);

        list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        itemName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
        itemName.setText("Select an item");

        quantity=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount));
        quantity.setEnabled(false);

        quantPlus=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
        quantMinus=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus);
        //addItem=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        quantPlus.setEnabled(false);
        quantMinus.setEnabled(false);



        itemPrice=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);


        final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, catagories);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

        catAdapter= new CategoriesAdapter(this.getActivity(),catForAdapter);
        spinner.setAdapter(catAdapter);        

 (this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, drinks);


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               selectedItem=(Items)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                selectedItemName=selectedItem.ItemName;
                selectedItemPrice=selectedItem.Price;
                itemName.setText(selectedItemName);
                itemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(selectedItemPrice));

                quantPlus.setEnabled(true);
                quantMinus.setEnabled(true);
                quantCount=1;
                quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount));
                addItem.setEnabled(true);
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                addItem.setEnabled(false);
                Categories ct= new Categories();
               ct= (Categories)spinner.getSelectedItem();
                    SoapCallClass s= new SoapCallClass();


                adapter=new ItemsAdapter(getActivity(),s.getItemsForCategory(ct.TOUCHCODE));
                quantCount=1;
                quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount));
                itemName.setText("Select Item");
                itemPrice.setText("0.00");
                quantPlus.setEnabled(false);
                quantMinus.setEnabled(false);

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }



            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

            }

        });

        quantPlus.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                            quantCount++;
                        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount));
                        itemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount*selectedItemPrice));

                        }


                }
        );

        quantMinus.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(quantCount>1)
                        quantCount--;
                        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount));
                        itemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount*selectedItemPrice));

                    }


                }
        );


        return  view;
    }
    OnAddItemPressed addItemPressed;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        addItemPressed=(OnAddItemPressed)getActivity();
        addItem=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        addItem.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        selectedItem.quantity=  quantCount;
       selectedItem.Ordered=false;
        addItemPressed.onAddItemPressed(selectedItem);
        addItem.setEnabled(false);
        quantCount=1;
        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount));
        itemName.setText("Select Item");
        itemPrice.setText("0.00");
        quantPlus.setEnabled(false);
        quantMinus.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

class Items{

    public String ItemName;
    public int ItemCode;
    public double Price;
    public int quantity;
    public int prevQuant;

    public String RESCODE;
    public int KOTDATE;
    public int KOTNUB;
    public int KOTTYP;
    public int STEWCODE;

    public String TBLNUB;
    public int PAXPER;
    public String PERSON;
    public String SESSON;
    public int SRLNUMB;

    public float ITMQTY;
    public float ITMRAT;
    public float ITMVAL;

    public int TAXSTR;
    public String KITCOD;

    public int MENTYP;
    public int GRPCOD;
    public int BILNUB;
    public int UPDFLG;
    public int BILSEQ;
    public int LSTDAT;

    public String LSTTIM;
    public String USERID;

    public float NCKPER;
    public String MODNAM;
    public String RORDER;

    public boolean Ordered;

}


class ItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Items> itemList;
    Context context;

    ItemsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Items> itemsArray) {
        itemList = new ArrayList<Items>();
        this.context = context;
        itemList=itemsArray;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }




    class ViewHolder {


        TextView txtView1;
        TextView txtView2;

        ViewHolder(View V) {
            txtView1 = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
            txtView2=(TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.txtItemPrice);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {


            row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Items it = itemList.get(position);
        holder.txtView1.setText(it.ItemName);

        holder.txtView2.setText(String.valueOf(it.Price));

        return row;
    }

}


class CategoriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Categories> catList;
    Context context;

    CategoriesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Categories> catArray) {
        catList = new ArrayList<Categories>();
        this.context = context;
        catList=catArray;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return catList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return catList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    class ViewHolder {


        TextView txtView1;
        //TextView txtView2;

        ViewHolder(View V) {
            txtView1 = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.txtcatrel);
           // txtView2=(TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.txtItemPrice);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {


            row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.categorylyt, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Categories ct = catList.get(position);
        holder.txtView1.setText(ct.Name);
        return row;
    }

}
```

**Code for Add Item button press from the Main Panel(Button whose text is barely visible)**

```
   OnAddItemPressed addItemPressed;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        addItemPressed=(OnAddItemPressed)getActivity();
        addItem=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        addItem.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        selectedItem.quantity=  quantCount;
       selectedItem.Ordered=false;
        addItemPressed.onAddItemPressed(selectedItem);
        addItem.setEnabled(false);
        quantCount=1;
        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount));
        itemName.setText("Select Item");
        itemPrice.setText("0.00");
        quantPlus.setEnabled(false);
        quantMinus.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

**Code for Interface which is implemented in Menu.java**

```
@Override
public void onAddItemPressed(Items item){

    FragmentManager manager= getFragmentManager();

    SidePanelFragment sideObj= (SidePanelFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.side_panel);
    sideObj.getAddedItems(item);


}
```

**Code to place the order**

```
     btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for(int i=0;i<itemsArray.size();i++){

                    if(!itemsArray.get(i).Ordered) {
                       // itemsArray.get(i).
                        itemsArray.get(i).Ordered = true;
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        adapter = new ItemsAdapter1(getActivity(), itemsArray);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list1.invalidateViews();
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
```

**Code to populate and display items in the listview**

```
    public void getAddedItems(Items item) {


        for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.size(); i++) {
            if (item.ItemName == itemsArray.get(i).ItemName) {
                int quant = itemsArray.get(i).prevQuant;
                item.quantity = item.quantity + quant;


                itemsArray.set(i, item);

                itemsArray.get(i).prevQuant = item.quantity;

                isPresent = true;

            }
        }

        if (!isPresent) {

            itemsArray.add(item);
            itemsArray.get(itemsArray.size() - 1).prevQuant = item.quantity;


        }



        isPresent = false;
        adapter = new ItemsAdapter1(getActivity(), itemsArray);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list1.invalidateViews();
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

After adding the items to the order and placing the order , `Ordered` property of the `Item` from `Items` class is set to true

Now , 
If you select an item and click place order and then add same item,  `Ordered` property of the **ordered item** becomes `false` which was `true` just after placing order and it gets added at that place and becomes blue which should not happen .If you add different items and place orders then this problem doesn't arise.Hope I've explained my question properly.

Comment: my eyes hurt while looking at your UI

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I know right! UI color scheme will be changed later but you know anything that could help me with the code?

Comment: i dont know, i didnt read your question well. its too long and have worst color pic. can you summarize your question to just include when and where your problem occur

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Last part of the question describes the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet solved the problem

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

               selectedItem=new Items();

          Items getItms=(Items)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            selectedItem.ItemCode=getItms.ItemCode;
            selectedItem.ItemName=getItms.ItemName;
            selectedItem.Price=getItms.Price;

                selectedItemName=selectedItem.ItemName;
                selectedItemPrice=selectedItem.Price;
                itemName.setText(selectedItemName);
                itemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(selectedItemPrice));

                quantPlus.setEnabled(true);
                quantMinus.setEnabled(true);
                quantCount=1;
                quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount));
                addItem.setEnabled(true);
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the flag **ordered** on the item itself, and reset it to false as soon as you click. You should consider managing **ordered** flag elsewhere than on the reference item itself. One may want to manage **Order** object with list of **ordered** items.

*Faulty* code

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        selectedItem.quantity=  quantCount;
        selectedItem.Ordered=false; // Here you reset the flag of "reference" item
        addItemPressed.onAddItemPressed(selectedItem);
        addItem.setEnabled(false);
        quantCount=1;
        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantCount));
        itemName.setText("Select Item");
        itemPrice.setText("0.00");
        quantPlus.setEnabled(false);
        quantMinus.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: so where should I put selectedItem.Ordered=false;  ?

Comment: As i said, i suggest creating a new *container* object, **Order** which contain list of items that will be ordered. selectedItem.Ordered property should move to **Order** object.